# Webpage under mod_pagespeed won't load SVG image

Tags: javascript, svg, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

few months ago I've installed Google's `mod_pagespeed` to my server. Everything worked as expected, but yesterday it stopped serve one SVG image and added some attributes to it's `<img />` tag: `onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"` and `data-pagespeed-url-hash="1225483209"`.

I'm really don't know what caused the issue, but AFAIK it stopped working without my action. File is presented on server.

The URL of website is https://www.datovasim.cz/ and image is in top right corner of page. File https://www.datovasim.cz/img/gomobil.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image file has had the namespace definitions removed. I.e. attributes of the form xmlns="something" and xmlns:something="something else" so it's no longer valid as an SVG file.

Comment: Thank you, solved! I switched to HTTPS, so I started using `//` instead of `http://` or `https://` and I changed it automatically for all files on server.

I forgot that `<DOCTYPE>` and other similiar tags (such as `<svg xmlns="">`) could cause this beavior when `http://` is replaced by `//`.